# cyclic bluetooth issues using a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 3

Tags: samsung, bluetooth, location-services

Anybody any idea what is the reason for cyclic bluetooth issues using a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 3? The connection shortly breaks/drops/becomes very slow after 3 seconds before recovering after 1 second. So I get:

- exactly 3 seconds of flawless Bluetooth
- exactly 1 second of broken Bluetooth
- exactly 3 seconds of flawless Bluetooth
- exactly 1 second of broken Bluetooth
- ...

Background:  We developed an Android App for the Samsung Galaxy Tab Active. It connects to a self-made Bluetooth sensor and communicates with that sensor non-stop at maximum bandwith. Now we are migrating to newer hardware and everything is looking good except for this one major issue. Some component interferes with bluetooth every 3 seconds. It probably does not matter too much for most users, but when streaming data at maximum bandwith it is a dealbreaker.

We tried many things:

Does not help:

- disable Wi-Fi
- disable "improve location accuracy" using Wi-Fi and Bluetooth
- disable Covid scanning
- disable nearby device scanning
- no bluetooth "app" to reset

Helps:

- Fully disable location

Do you have any idea what is going on here and how to work around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to perform your tests in a different environment? May be the problems are caused by other devices near-by.

Comment: @Robert good idea, but we tried different devices, different editions (T570 Wifi, T575 LTE), at diffferent locations, using different bluetooth sensors that work flawless with other Android devices. It quite certainly is an issue with the Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 3.